# procedure with iterations of the first step Newton's method in Moore's form

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I have to write the **procedure with iterations** of the first step Newton's method in Moore's form in Mathematica8, exactly on this example: 
**GIVEN:**

> f[x_]:=x*x-8*x+7; inter={5, 9}; eps = 10^(-6);

**TO CALCULATE:**

> x0 := Mean[{5, 9}]; 
>       f[x0] ; 
>       f'[x_] ; 
>       f'[inter]; 
>       n0 = x0 - f[x0]/f'[inter]; 
>       x1 = IntervalIntersection[inter,n0];

I tried to do it, but it doesn't calculate iterations correctly :

```
f[x_]:=x*x-8*x+7
inter := Interval[{5, 9}]
x0 := Mean[{5, 9}]
newton[f_,x0,eps_]:=Module[{old,new,iter,step},
old ;
step[old] := IntervalIntersection[inter, x0 - (f[x0])/(f'[inter])];
new = step[old];
iter=0;
While[Abs[old-new]>eps,
old = new;
new = step[old];
iter++];
Print["Iterations = ", iter];
Print["X1 = ", new];
]
newton[f,x0,0.00001]
```

HELP PLEASE  !!!

Comment: Print the value of f'[ inter ] before you use it and think about that.

Comment: then it just outputs f'[inter] = Interval[{2,10}]; Iterations = 0 ; X1 = Interval[{7,7}].    SO it calculates f'[inter] correctly

Comment: there is a bunch of stuff going on here.  Local symbol `old` is initially undefined. The statement `old;` does nothing. `step[old]:=` creates a delayed definition of `step` only for that undefined symbol `old`. Once you actually define `old` your function will no longer recognize it. Perhaps you mean `step[old_]`? but since the r.h.s doesn't depend on `old` I cant see what that is supposed to do. Likewise the `x0` in `newton` should likely be `x0_`.

Comment: my advice, put the interval arithmetic aside and first implement a plain old newton method approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this up sticking with your basic loop structure as much as possible.

```
step[f_, inter_] := Module[{x = Mean@First@(List @@ inter)},
      IntervalIntersection[inter, x - (f[x])/(f'[inter])]]
newton[f_, inter0_, eps_] := Module[{iter,inter},
    inter = inter0;
    iter = 0;
    While[Abs[Subtract @@ First@(List @@ inter)] > eps,
        inter = step[f, inter];
        iter++;
        Print["loop count",iter,inter,
             x = N@Mean@First@(List @@ inter),f[x],f'[inter]]];
    Print["Iterations = ", iter];
    Print["X1 = ", N@Mean@First@(List @@ inter)];]
f[x_] = x^2 - 8 x + 7 ;
inter = Interval[{5, 10}] ;
newton[f, inter, 0.00001];
```

result `7.` in `4` iterations

of course in mathematical there are usually cleaner approaches than a do loop:

```
 newton[f_, inter0_, eps_] := Module[{iter = 0},
    Print["X1 = ", N@Mean@First@(List @@
        NestWhile[(++iter; step[f, #]) &, inter0, 
           Abs[Subtract @@ First@(List @@ #)] > eps & ])];
 Print["iter=", iter]]
```

Note this only works properly if the sign of the derivative does not change in the initial `Interval`. Otherwise you end up with multiple intervals. I'm not that familiar with interval arithmetic to readily see how to deal with that.

Comment: AAAAND PLEASEEEE tell me how to output some calculated results like inter, x, f(x), f'[inter] after each iteration. e.g. in my example iterations=4, so after 1st iteration: inter=?, x=?, f(x)=?, f'[inter]=?..and after the other.

Comment: i put a print statement as an example.  If you want to *save* those results for later use look up `Reap/Sow`